# Problema con Multiprocessing y Process en GUI con Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, windows10

estoy diseñando una GUI con Tkinter en python 2.7 para un proyecto que esta funcionando (https://github.com/codebox/mosaic). El proyecto realiza un fotomosaico a partir de un banco de imágenes, lo realiza a través de la libreria Pillow.

El script al trabajar con procesamiento de imágenes utiliza la librería multiprocessing para usar todos los núcleos disponibles del CPU (o al menos eso entiendo).

El problema surge cuando después de modificar el código para obtener los datos desde TKinter a traves de los widgets de Entry y demás, obtengo un error que me clava el script pero no genera ninguna advertencia ni nada por consola. Por las pruebas que estuve haciendo, el error (al parecer) esta en los argumentos de la llamada de ejecución del proceso. Quisiera por favor si pueden, darle una mirada y darme su opinión...

Los valores que estoy usando para la prueba del script son:

Recortar Mosaico=50
Resolucion Mosaico=4
Agrandamiento=8

El script falla llegado a este punto:

```
Process(target=build_mosaic, args=(result_queue, all_tile_data_large, original_img_large, tamanio)).start()
```

ahi se cuelga y para cerrar la interfaz windows me pide finalizar python.

les dejo el script entero para ver si pueden darme una mano.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Mar 09 19:59:07 2017

@author: Daniel
"""

import sys, os, tkFileDialog, unicodedata
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, cpu_count
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
WORKER_COUNT = max(cpu_count() - 1, 1) #selecciona el maximo entre 1 y 1 menos el numero de procesador 
EOQ_VALUE = None #inicializa una variable como un objeto del tipo None (nada)    
salida = 'mosaico.jpeg' #da le nombre al archivo que se crea
class TileProcessor:
   def __init__(self, tiles_directory, tamanio, ENLARGEMENT, TILE_BLOCK_SIZE):
       self.tiles_directory = tiles_directory
       self.tamanio=tamanio
       self.ENLARGEMENT=ENLARGEMENT
       self.TILE_BLOCK_SIZE=TILE_BLOCK_SIZE

   def __process_tile(self, tile_path):
       try:
           img = Image.open(tile_path)
           # los mosaicos deben ser cuadrados, entonces seleciona el minimo entre largo y ancho y los recorta
           w = img.size[0]
           h = img.size[1]
           min_dimension = min(w, h)
           w_crop = (w - min_dimension) / 2
           h_crop = (h - min_dimension) / 2 
           img = img.crop((w_crop, h_crop, w - w_crop, h - h_crop))

           large_tile_img = img.resize((self.tamanio, self.tamanio), Image.ANTIALIAS)
           small_tile_img = img.resize((self.tamanio/self.TILE_BLOCK_SIZE, self.tamanio/self.TILE_BLOCK_SIZE), Image.ANTIALIAS)

           return (large_tile_img.convert('RGB'), small_tile_img.convert('RGB'))
       except:
           return (None, None)

   def get_tiles(self):
       large_tiles = []
       small_tiles = []
       #i=1
       print 'Leyendo mosaicos de \'%s\'...' % (self.tiles_directory, )
       #print (tamanio)
       # se buscan los mosaicos recursivamente en las subcarpetas de la direccion
       for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(self.tiles_directory):
           for tile_name in files:
               tile_path = os.path.join(root, tile_name)
               large_tile, small_tile = self.__process_tile(tile_path)
               if large_tile:
                   large_tiles.append(large_tile)
                   small_tiles.append(small_tile)

       print 'Se procesaron %s mosaicos.' % (len(large_tiles),)


       return (large_tiles, small_tiles)

class TargetImage:
   def __init__(self, image_path, ENLARGEMENT, TILE_BLOCK_SIZE, tamanio):
       self.image_path = image_path
       self.ENLARGEMENT=ENLARGEMENT
       self.TILE_BLOCK_SIZE=TILE_BLOCK_SIZE
       self.tamanio=tamanio
   def get_data(self):
       print 'Procesando imagen principal...'
       img = Image.open(self.image_path)
       w = img.size[0] * self.ENLARGEMENT  #tamaño ancho
       h = img.size[1]    * self.ENLARGEMENT #tamaño alto
       large_img = img.resize((w, h), Image.ANTIALIAS) #retorna una copia cambiada de tamaño y filtrada con antialias
       w_diff = (w % self.tamanio)/2
       h_diff = (h % self.tamanio)/2
       print()
       # si es necesario recorta la imagen ligeramente para utilizar un numero entero de mosaicos horizontales y verticales
       if w_diff or h_diff:
           large_img = large_img.crop((w_diff, h_diff, w - w_diff, h - h_diff)) #recorta la imagen de cada lado es decir 4 datos necesarios
       small_img = large_img.resize((w/self.TILE_BLOCK_SIZE, h/self.TILE_BLOCK_SIZE), Image.ANTIALIAS)
       image_data = (large_img.convert('RGB'), small_img.convert('RGB'))
       print 'Imagen principal procesada.'
       return image_data

class TileFitter:
   def __init__(self, tiles_data):
       self.tiles_data = tiles_data

   def __get_tile_diff(self, t1, t2, bail_out_value):
       diff = 0
       for i in range(len(t1)):
           #diff += (abs(t1[i][0] - t2[i][0]) + abs(t1[i][1] - t2[i][1]) + abs(t1[i][2] - t2[i][2]))
           diff += ((t1[i][0] - t2[i][0])**2 + (t1[i][1] - t2[i][1])**2 + (t1[i][2] - t2[i][2])**2)
           if diff > bail_out_value:
               # we know already that this isnt going to be the best fit, so no point continuing with this tile
               return diff
       return diff

   def get_best_fit_tile(self, img_data):
       best_fit_tile_index = None
       min_diff = sys.maxint
       tile_index = 0

       # go through each tile in turn looking for the best match for the part of the image represented by 'img_data'
       for tile_data in self.tiles_data:
           diff = self.__get_tile_diff(img_data, tile_data, min_diff)
           if diff < min_diff:
               min_diff = diff
               best_fit_tile_index = tile_index
           tile_index += 1

       return best_fit_tile_index

def fit_tiles(work_queue, result_queue, tiles_data):
   # this function gets run by the worker processes, one on each CPU core
   tile_fitter = TileFitter(tiles_data)

   while True:
       try:
           img_data, img_coords = work_queue.get(True)
           if img_data == EOQ_VALUE:
               break
           tile_index = tile_fitter.get_best_fit_tile(img_data)
           result_queue.put((img_coords, tile_index))
       except KeyboardInterrupt:
           pass

   # let the result handler know that this worker has finished everything
   result_queue.put((EOQ_VALUE, EOQ_VALUE))

class ProgressCounter:
   def __init__(self, total):
       self.total = total
       self.counter = 0

   def update(self):
       self.counter += 1
       sys.stdout.write("Progress: %s%% %s" % (100 * self.counter / self.total, "\r"))
       sys.stdout.flush();

class MosaicImage:
   def __init__(self, original_img, tamanio):
       self.tamanio=tamanio
       print(tamanio)
       self.image = Image.new(original_img.mode, original_img.size)
       self.x_tile_count = original_img.size[0] / self.tamanio
       self.y_tile_count = original_img.size[1] / self.tamanio
       self.total_tiles  = self.x_tile_count * self.y_tile_count
       print('ajam..')
   def add_tile(self, tile_data, coords):
       img = Image.new('RGB', (self.tamanio, self.tamanio))
       img.putdata(tile_data)
       self.image.paste(img, coords)

   def save(self, path):
       self.image.save(path)

def build_mosaic(result_queue, all_tile_data_large, original_img_large, tamanio):
   mosaic = MosaicImage(original_img_large, tamanio)

   active_workers = WORKER_COUNT
   print('fuera')
   while True:
       try:
           img_coords, best_fit_tile_index = result_queue.get()

           if img_coords == EOQ_VALUE:
               print('dentro')
               active_workers -= 1
               if not active_workers:
                   break
           else:
               print('else')
               tile_data = all_tile_data_large[best_fit_tile_index]
               mosaic.add_tile(tile_data, img_coords)

       except KeyboardInterrupt:
           pass

   mosaic.save(salida)
   print '\nFinalizado, la imagen de salida se encuentra en', salida

def terminal(original_img, tiles, tamanio, TILE_BLOCK_SIZE): # terminal determina la parte visual del programa en la terminal de windows
   print 'Construyendo imagen, Ctrl+C para abortar...'
   tamanio=tamanio
   original_img_large, original_img_small = original_img
   tiles_large, tiles_small = tiles

   mosaic = MosaicImage(original_img_large, tamanio)

   all_tile_data_large = map(lambda tile : list(tile.getdata()), tiles_large)
   all_tile_data_small = map(lambda tile : list(tile.getdata()), tiles_small)

   work_queue   = Queue(WORKER_COUNT)    
   result_queue = Queue()
   print('aqui')
   try:
       print('hola hola')
       # start the worker processes that will build the mosaic image 

#todo funciona perfecto hasta este punto... luego de esta orden de ejecutar este proceso el script falla... 
       Process(target=build_mosaic, args=(result_queue, all_tile_data_large, original_img_large, tamanio)).start()
       print('hola')
       # start the worker processes that will perform the tile fitting
       for n in range(WORKER_COUNT):
           Process(target=fit_tiles, args=(work_queue, result_queue, all_tile_data_small)).start()

       progress = ProgressCounter(mosaic.x_tile_count * mosaic.y_tile_count)
       print('hola 2')
       for x in range(mosaic.x_tile_count):
           for y in range(mosaic.y_tile_count):
               large_box = (x * tamanio, y * tamanio, (x + 1) * tamanio, (y + 1) * tamanio)
               small_box = (x * tamanio/TILE_BLOCK_SIZE, y * tamanio/TILE_BLOCK_SIZE, (x + 1) * tamanio/TILE_BLOCK_SIZE, (y + 1) * tamanio/TILE_BLOCK_SIZE)
               work_queue.put((list(original_img_small.crop(small_box).getdata()), large_box))
               progress.update()

   except:
       print '\nGuardando imagen parcial, espere...'

   finally:
       print('aqui tambien')
       # put these special values onto the queue to let the workers know they can terminate
       for n in range(WORKER_COUNT):
           work_queue.put((EOQ_VALUE, EOQ_VALUE))

def mosaic(): # definicion del metodo mosaic
   tamanio   = int(entero1.get())# alto y ancho de los mosaicos en pixeles
   TILE_MATCH_RES = int(entero2.get())    # tile matching resolution (higher values give better fit but require more processing)
   ENLARGEMENT    = int(entero3.get())    # la imagen mosaico sera esta cantidad de veces mas grande (en largo y ancho) que la imagen original    
   TILE_BLOCK_SIZE = tamanio / max(min(TILE_MATCH_RES, tamanio), 1) #tamaño del bloque final
   os.remove('C:\Users\Daniel Doyharzabal\Desktop\Imagenes\principal.pyc')



   path=tkFileDialog.askdirectory()
   label_6.config(text=path)
   archivo=tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
   label_7.config(text=archivo)
   tiles_path=path #"C:/ImageOutput"
   img_path=archivo #"C:/nene.jpg"
   print(tiles_path)
   print(img_path)
   tiles_data = TileProcessor(tiles_path, tamanio, ENLARGEMENT, TILE_BLOCK_SIZE).get_tiles() # utiliza la direccion de los mosaicos de entrada para iniciar el procesamiento
   image_data = TargetImage(img_path, ENLARGEMENT, TILE_BLOCK_SIZE, tamanio).get_data()  #
   terminal(image_data, tiles_data, tamanio, TILE_BLOCK_SIZE)

if __name__ == '__main__': #verifica si el modulo ha sido importado o si es ejecutado como modulo principal (main)

   root=Tk()
   root.title("Fotomosaico con Python")
   root.geometry('650x400+200+200')

   label_1= Label(root, text="Recortar Mosaicos")
   label_2= Label(root, text="Resolucion Mosaicos")
   label_3= Label(root, text="Agrandamiento")
   label_4= Label(root, text="Direccion de Mosaicos")
   label_5= Label(root, text="Direccion de Imagen")
   label_6= Label(root, text="...")
   label_7= Label(root, text="...")
   label_8= Label(root, text="...")

   x=StringVar()
   y=StringVar()
   z=StringVar()

   entero1= Entry(root, textvariable='x')
   entero2= Entry(root, textvariable='y')
   entero3= Entry(root, textvariable='z')

   label_1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E)
   label_2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E)
   label_3.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=E)
   label_4.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=E)
   label_5.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=E)
   label_6.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W) #direccion mosaicos
   label_7.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W) #direccion imagen

   entero1.grid(row=0, column=1)
   entero2.grid(row=1, column=1)
   entero3.grid(row=2, column=1)

   boton_3=Button(root, text="Aceptar", command= mosaic )
   boton_3.grid(column= 4, row=5)


   root.mainloop() #ejecuta la GUI


else :
   print ('fallo')
```

me siento bastante frustrado con esto porque hace bastante tiempo intento hacerlo funcionar sin resultados.  Muchas gracias desde ya...